# Why is Windows Backup forcing me to include a non system drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, windows-backup

I'm trying to update my backup image, which *should* only includes the C drive.... except now Windows backup is forcing me to include my D drive and labeling it as a system drive, even though it doesn't do anything special (hosts a large VM and some other files) - shown below.  I've also include an image from disk management, in case it helps.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: windows backup]
[image: d drive]
[image: partition manager]

Answer (score 1):

Like all things in life, a reboot solved my problem.  I'd still love to know *why* Windows felt the D drive should be backed up.... I suspect it felt it required something running from the D drive (I did have realtemp running, which is located in the portable folder in the image above.... though I ran it manually not via Windows startup).